# How to proxy context to different backend context in apache

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy, cherrypy

I'd like to configure apache so that http://my-domain.com/myapp serves a Python webapp running in CherryPy on a backend server.

Here's what's in the vhost:

```
    RewriteRule ^/myapp/?(.*) http://backend-server:8000/$1 [P]
    ProxyPassReverse /myapp/ http://backend-server:8000/
```

When I trace the request/response, I see:

```
GET /myapp HTTP/1.1
Host: my-domain.com
```

And then:

```
HTTP/1.1 303 See Other
Date: Thu, 15 Sep 2011 21:46:35 GMT
Server: CherryPy/3.1.2
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Location: http://my-domain.com/somwhere-else/
```

As you can see, the CherryPy webapp sends a 303 redirect to /somewhere-else/

Any ideas why the Apache ProxyPassReverse doesn't transform the Location to `http://my-domain.com/myapp/somewhere-else`?

Answer (score 1):

Your source location is `/myapp`, while your `ProxyPassReverse` is for `/myapp/`; context of the proxied location doesn't match, so the `ProxyPassReverse` doesn't apply.

Why the mod_rewrite proxy?  This should accomplish the same, and have no trailing slash consistency issues:

```
ProxyPass /myapp http://backend-server:8000
ProxyPassReverse /myapp http://backend-server:8000
```

Comment: Thanks much for the reply. I tried your suggestion, but, unfortunately, I'm seeing the same response. Perhaps I'm missing some other Apache directive? I'll keep digging....

Comment: @Dave CherryPy might be getting sensitive about the `Host:` header - try adding `ProxyPreserveHost on`.  Still, Apache should catch and translate that redirect, unless it doesn't think it should; is there anything different about the new URL versus the old?  Host name (is there a `www`?), port, protocol - any difference in these things to the original request will cause Apache to leave the `Location:` header alone.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem and fix it as follow:

For some reason both context path must be the same so, I mod my application context path to be the equal (note extra "/" on passResever)

```
    ProxyPass               /jira           http://192.168.1.30:8080/jira
    ProxyPassReverse        /jira/          http://192.168.1.30:8080/jira
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the backend app serves back a Location header with the public  name "my-domain.com", so ProxyPassReverse doesn't recognize it. The backend server should not know  the public name (frontend name), it should only know itself by the name "backend-server".